# Laravel Job scheduler fails when querying "myproj_cache_illuminate:schedule:interrupt" in database

Tags: php, laravel

I've moved my Laravel 10 project and its MySQL 8 database from a soon to be EOL CentOS 7 server to one running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  It all works, except that every time cron runs "php artisan schedule:run" this error is written to the log file:

```
Caught exception Illuminate\Database\QueryException:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: delete from `cache` where `key` = myproj_cache_illuminate:schedule:interrupt)
```

A consequence of this is that none of the tasks in app\Console\Kernel.php are run.

The cache table in the database is empty (as it is on the original server), but this error is still reported if I manually insert an entry with "myproj_cache_illuminate:schedule:interrupt" as its key and 0 as its value.

Searching the Laravel source code, this seems to be triggered by ScheduleRunCommand::clearInterruptSignal but I don't know how to debug that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working, but I'm not exactly sure why.  The server runs cPanel which may explain why the user of the account involved couldn't run "crontab -e" due to access rights, so I did it as root.  Then I found that cPanel has a tool to edit an account's crontab so I used that and the problem went away.